# PHP: Transfer images as binary in JSON

Tags: php, json, ftp, binary, ascii

Huy guys,

I need to transfer a larger amount of files from one server to another as a sort of "update/re-install process" for the application I'm building.

So far the files have been pushed by a main server via FTP. This works well, but I want to get rid of storing client's FTP information and want to turn the push-method into a pull-method. So the client clicks "Update" and the client server receives the files.

I've been looking into Phar, Zip and other ways of packing files, but they require extensions and I want my application to be at least extension-dependent as possible.

So I've resorted to transfering the files with JSON. The main/source server packs all the files in a JSON array and sends it to the client server upon request, and the client server loops over the files and saves them. It works perfectly well for PHP,JavaScript, etc. but some images are corrupted in the process.

I suspect it is due to the fact that the data is transfered as ASCII rather than binary, because I encountered the same problem when I built the installation with FTP, and when I turned to binary transfer instead of ASCII the images were no longer corrupted.

Does anybody here have a solution to getting the images transfered non-corrupted?
I use file_get_contents, and have used it in other projects to open and save image data, so I know the function can handle it. I suspect the JSON will need to do some additional encoding or something like that to correctly transfer the image content?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with base64.That is the simplest way to transfer binary data with php.